# Hide Section After Click to "Add to cart"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I need to hide an HTML section within the product sheet, after the user clicks on "add to cart". I have set the following code but without success. I also tried adding a CSS via  directly into my theme's success.php file but without getting results.

```
<?php

if ( !function_exists( 'wc_print_notices' ) ) { 
    require_once '/includes/wc-notice-functions.php'; 
    
    $display_none_on = "none";
}else{
    
}

?>

<span style="display: <?php echo $display_none_on; ?>">
    
    <?php
wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' ); 

?>

</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$hid = “div_to_hide”;
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($pageUrl);
$target_elem = $dom->getElementById(hid);
if ($target_elem) {
    $target_elem-> setAttribute('style','display: none;');
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the code but it doesn't works with Woocommerce